# Django REST API - HyperlinkedRelatedField - How do you create link between parent and child?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I've picked up Python again and started learning Django REST Framework after a long time out.

I have a case where I have a Parent with a one to many relationship with a Child class, see below. I can create the parent through the REST API and a I can create a Child but how do I link the two together when I create the Child? Is it also possible to link the two together post Child creation event?

```python
class ChildSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('id',
                  'created', 'name', 'region')

class ParentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    children = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='child-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('id',
                  'created', 'name','region', 'children')
```